# Firebase returning a map object to loop over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am relatively new to react and firebase, learning as i go. This is for a personal project i am working on in my free time.

I have a map object in firestore which i am wanting to loop over and return to the ouput to the web page. I am getting the data from firebase then setting the state once it has been returned.

```
const [advertData, setAdvertData] = useState(null);

const advertData = async () => {
try {
    const docRef = doc(getFirestore(), "dataIndex", s);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
        setAdvertData(docSnap.data()); 
      }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
```

An example of what is returned can be found here:

[image: Firebase example data]

Next i want to be able to loop over the lap, displaying the values only as list items.
The bit i am unsure of is, when i try this in the page like so:

```
{advertData?.experienceLevel.map((p, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <h2>Name: {p}</h2>
      <hr />
     </div>
   );
})}
```

I get this error in the browser

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

I am unsure how to resolve this, i have tried adding `advertData?.experienceLevel` however i get the same error as above. I believe its because its trying to populate the map while the advertData is been set from firebase.

Thanks for your help in advance and apologies for what may seem a a very basic question to most.

Comment: `experienceLevel` is `undefined`. Does adding another "?" after "experienceLevel" fix the issue? i.e. `advertData?.experienceLevel?.map(...)`

Comment: Thanks, no it didnt help adding the advertData?.experienceLevel?.map(...) like this, but instead i added a conditional check before rendering the button and that resolved the issue. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to optional chain (change `.` to `?.`) after `experienceLevel` as well, since before you get the data fully loaded, that key is possible to be `undefined` (as shown in your error, it definitely is `undefined`).

```js
advertData?.experienceLevel?.map(// rest of stuff
```